# Mono doesn't find ExcelProvider.dll

Tags: f#

I installed the ExcelProvider on my MacOS (running F# 4.5 and mono 6.0.0.327)

```
nuget install ExcelProvider
```

Now I created an empty directory and created a single file called Foo.fs and wrote this code

```
open FSharp.Interop.Excel
type DataTypeTest = ExcelFile<"DataTypeTest.xlsx">
let file = new DataTypeTest()
let row = file.Data |> Seq.head
printfn "This is column 1 %s" row.Test1
printfn "This is column 2 %s" row.Test2
```

Created an Excel file called DataTypeTest.xlsx in the same directory created a 2 columns Test1 and Test2 and added some data below them

compiled it using

```
fsharpc -r:/Users/foo/ExcelProvider.1.0.1/lib/netstandard2.0/ExcelProvider.Runtime.dll -o:Foo.exe Excel.fs
```

This compiled fine and I got Foo.exe

Now I order to make mono be able to find my Excel Provider Dll. I created a config file called Foo.exe.config and copied the following content

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <providing privatePath="/Users/srabh/ExcelProvider.1.0.1/lib/netstandard2.0" />
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but when I run my code using `mono ./Foo.exe` it still doesn't find

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelProvider.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'ExcelProvider.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'ExcelProvider.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
File name: 'ExcelProvider.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

Comment: You should probably use VS/Rider/VS Code to create your project so you can avoid this type of manual intervention. DId you mean `probing PrivatePath`?  That will search the base directory of your app, so I suggest try moving the dll there. If your package is in the cache then use`   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DLLNAME" Version="VERSIONNUMBER" />
  </ItemGroup>`

Comment: I am just using VSCode on Mac. I don't have access to the "big" visual studio.

Comment: No problem. Have you installed ionide with fsharp and paket?

Comment: I just did "brew install mono" and then I installed vscode separately.

Comment: https://fsharp.org/use/mac/ doesn't talk about Ionide or packet. I followed "Option 5: Install F# with Mono via Homebrew (64-bit)" in this document.

Comment: Maybe you should come by the F# Slack for some more help. I believe setting up the development environment correctly will help you a lot down the road. Option 5 also talks about this `You can configure Xamarin Studio to use this 64-bit installation: Preferences > .NET Runtimes > Add > /usr/local` Anyway, to make the long story short, plz install dotnet core 3 preview 9 or later and add ionide-fsharp and paket to vscode. Than you can create projects and packages etc from the editor. For the Slack see: http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/

Comment: Why Mono? It definitely should be possible to use TP with mono and compile single *.fs file without *.fsproj, but it is hard way. It should be way easier with .NET Core and *.fsproj file created by `dotnet new`
Do you have `ExcelProvider.Runtime.dll` (and all dependencies) in working directory near `Foo.exe`?

Comment: The problem is Microsoft way of thinking. I don't want to use fsproj. I come from java /scala/python background where there is no mandate to use a "project". I can just work with a directory with source code files in it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add have `probing privatePath` in the config file, and have the dll in the directory or subdirectory of your app. Please see: [Configure Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element).

Best is actually not to use the compiler or msbuild directly as you will start running into problems quickly (as you noticed). Instead plz use Rider/VS Code/VS (they all run on mac). It will simplify package management and building and maintain your projects. Install ionide extensions into VSCode if you chose it.